# CUDA aware ROS node

Tags: ros, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a CUDA newbie. I managed to install CUDA on my lucid (Ref: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625433 ) and I am able to run all the examples  in the SDK. Now I am trying to have CUDA aware ros node.

I tried http://www.ros.org/wiki/cuda. But it is compiling forever (> 3hrs ).
[ I killed the make and it messed up with my nvidia driver.
I then have to re-install the nvdia drivers]

Is there anything else I should do before rosmaking the gpgpu stack ?
(http://www.ros.org/wiki/cuda).

Gajan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11389/cuda-aware-ros-node/) by [gajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/201/gajan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-10-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-04-24**:
hello , my question http://answers.ros.org/question/60862/how-to-use-cuda-in-ros-furete/   ,can you give me some advice about above question/     thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you not use the gpgpu stack at all; instead, install CUDA like you would any third-party library dependency, and add CUDA-appropriate lines to your package's `CMakeLists`.

Put differently, treat your ROS package like you would any other compile that needs CUDA; don't try to get CUDA through ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason for the slow compile is that you probably already have the CUDA SDK installed. The rosmake is getting caught on this:

### A previous version of CUDA was found in /usr/local/cuda/bin
Would you like to uninstall? (yes/no/abort): Signal caught, cleaning up

The above is the output after I aborted my rosmake.

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1